# Yii: enable profiling for admin user only

Tags: php, yii, profiling

How to enable DB profiling for admin user only? If I define it statically in *config*, application doesn't yet know if user is admin or not.

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, in controller you can do:

```
public function init(){
    $role=Rbac::role(Yii::app()->user->id);
    if($role=="admin"){
        Yii::app()->db->enableProfiling=true;
    }
    return parent::init();
}
```

Please note that, I assumed that a we have a class called `Rbac` and it has a method which gets user roles by user id(`role()`).

Also, if you have a module, you can check that into `init()` method same as controller. Even if you have a base controller class, you can do so. You can also do that in controller `beforeAction()` method, if you need to skip that for some specific actions.

To do this more elegant, you can create a `behavior` and attach it to controller or put that in `preload` config file.

Another way is to do this while user logging in process in `UserIdentity` class, to set a state of enabling profiling, or doing that after login success in-line.